# Сделать проверку для значения

Tags: java, android, try-catch

Есть метод:

```
public String formatString(String str, int resId) {
    return String.format("%s %s", context.getResources().getString(resId), str);
}
```

Как правильно для него сделать проверку(с помощью `try` / `catch`),чтоб `int resId` не равнялось 0, а именно если оно равнялось вдруг 0, то действие бы не выполнялось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужна проверка только на равенство/неравенство `resId` нулю, то `try-catch` не нужен и можно обойтись простым `if-else`.

Если же Вы хотите именно с `try-catch`, то:

```
public String formatString(String str, int resId) {
    String result = "";
    try {
        result = String.format("%s %s", context.getResources().getString(resId), str);
    } catch(Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        // обработка исключения
    }
    return result;
}
```

Здесь обрабатывается исключение `Resources.NotFoundException`, которое генерируется в тех случаях, когда ресурс с заданным `resId` не найден (в частности, если `resId == 0`).

Comment: извините, а где здесь фигурирует, что значение не должно равняться нулю?

Comment: @Inkognito, Обновил ответ.

Comment: то что надо. единственное что пишет что catch пустой. в обработку исключения входит типо надпись, что вы ввели 0 или же что то другое?

Comment: @Inkognito, Я не знаю, каким образом должна работать **Ваша** программа в этой ситуации. Поведение программы в подобных случаях задается ее разработчиком и только им. Сторонние люди Вам чего-то **конкретного** в этой ситуации посоветовать не смогут. Можете выводить сообщение, что строка с таким идентификатором не найдена, а можете делать что-то другое.

Answer (score 0):

Вы сами то вопрос читали? Отловить условие? Что?

Насколько я понял вы хотите проверить не равняется ли resId нулю. Если знаете что делать, в случае, когда он окажется нулем, то обычным if:

```
if (resId == 0) { ... }
```

Если не знаете, генерируйте исключение:

```
if (resId == 0) { throw new IllegalArgumentAxception("resId = 0!") }
```

Comment: подправил вопрос. Хочу чтобы при `resId == 0` действие не выполялось бы. + как правильно связать именно с моим методом не знаю.

Comment: Всё равно не верно. Что значит действие не выполнилось? Если бы тип функции был void, то есть она по сути просто делает некое действие, более профессиональным языком, имеет побочный эффект, то можно было бы через проверку. Но тут у вас функция возвращает String, а значит вы должны решить, что будет возвращаться, в случае resId = 0. Если вы просто выводите, это может быть и пустая строка "" и какая нибудь строка "undefined". А если вы не знаете что вернуть, можно вернуть null или бросить исключение. Но тогда во внешнем коде нужно будет думать об обработке таких ситуаций.

Answer (score 0):

А не легче ли при вызове метода сделать проверку

```
if (resId != 0){
   formatString(myString, resId);
}
```